# How many rows can SQL Server process in a single INSERT statement into a table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, data-warehouse, azure-sql-data-warehouse

To illustrate my question, the following is a query detecting order's id which have not been inserted in a data warehouse and inserts them:

```
With NewOrders 
As
(   
    Select OrderID From Orders
    Except
    Select OrderID From FactOrders
)
Insert Into FactOrders(OrderID, OrderDate, CustomerId)
    Select OrderID, OrderDate, CustomerId From Orders
    Where OrderID in (Select OrderID from NewOrders);
```

Say the query is run for the first time and `Orders` contains 400 million rows or more:

Can SQL Server handle this number of rows in one single `INSERT` statement?

If not, how should I proceed? Should I limit the number of rows fetched in the `INSERT` statement? How many rows can the engine handle in a single `INSERT` statement?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) the only limitation on the number of rows stored per table is as below

> Limited only by available resources

What local resources does this *potentially* include?

- Memory
- Space in the database data files to physically write the inserted data to
- Space in the database log files
- Space in TempDB (Data and log)

As for how much a single SELECT statement can extract, I cannot find any documentation pertaining to this directly, but I would assume it is safe to take this to be exactly the same as the above.

Answer (score 3):

There does not appear to be a row limit except as it relates to resources. If your SQL Server truly have enough resources to insert half a billion rows then it will do it. In the past, I have been faced with such resource constraints, so I would add a WHERE clause that limited the resultset. Or I would run the INSERT recursively with a TOP on the select.

```
With NewOrders 
As
(   
    Select OrderID From Orders
    Except
    Select OrderID From FactOrders
)
Insert Into FactOrders(OrderID, OrderDate, CustomerId)
Select **TOP 1000000** OrderID, OrderDate, CustomerId 
  From Orders
 Where OrderID in (Select OrderID from NewOrders);
```